# single byte, locale and index scan in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, locale

Is there any relation between single byte character locale and index scan in postgreSQL?
I already read the pages in https://www.postgresql.org/doc, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. The important division is not between single-byte and multi-byte locales, but between the `C` (or `POSIX`) locale and all others.

The `C` locale is English with a sort order (collation) that sorts words character by character, with lower code points (for example, ASCII values) sorted before higher ones. Because this collation is much simpler than natural language collations, comparisons and sorting are much faster with the `C` locale. Moreover, and this is where indexes come in, a simple B-tree index on a string column can support `LIKE` conditions, because words are ordered character by character. With other collations, you need to use the `text_pattern_ops` operator class to support `LIKE`.

So if you can live with the strange sort order of the `C` collation, use the `C` locale by all means.

Do not use any single-byte locales, ever. Even with the `C` locale, use the encoding `UTF8`. There is no benefit in choosing any other encoding, and you will find it quite annoying if you encounter a character that you want to store in your database, but cannot.